# Android OnDraw() and update with Timer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a game in Android that once a user presses start, there will be objects flying across the screen. I think I need to link my OnDraw() function with a timer so that the objects' positions can be updated.

Currently, I am following a code sample I found online that prints out the text continuously.
However, I can't import java.awt.event.ActionEvent and ActionListener. Eclipse is giving me a "The import java.awt.event cannot be resolved". Is there an Android equivalent to ActionEvent?
Or is this done some other way? Thank you.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerSample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Hello World Timer");
      }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, actionListener);
    timer.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) which android provides and for a from the scratch tutorial, check out [this](http://writecodeeasy.blogspot.com/2012/08/androidtutorial-timer-p1.html).